# Sqlite query not working when running on android device

Tags: android

I am using few update queries to update my tables(Sqlite). They are working very well on my emulator. But, when I installed on my phone, they dont return sucess. At the same time,it does not throw any errors also. 
This is my code:

```
               ContentValues msg_values = new ContentValues();
    msg_values.put("folder_id", 1);
    int i=getContentResolver().update(MBContants.CONTENT_URI_SMS, msg_values,
            "address=" + msg.getAddress(), null);
    if(i>0)
    System.out.println("done..!");

    else
        Log.i("--------------------------------------------","not done");
```

Where, I've created my db and the URI to my table is MBContants.CONTENT_URI_SMS, where MBContants class holds all the URI's.

Please help solve this issue.
Thanks,
Viashnavi

Comment: Try uninstalling your app completely and reinstalling it.

Comment: are the databases the same (including data) between the 2 environments?

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your app from the phone.  Don't forget to turn debugging on in the phone's settings.  Set a breackpoint at the start of this logic and step through to see what happens.  I'm sure the answer will be pretty obvious once you do that.

Comment: Please post your solution for everyone to see.   Also, accept my answer if it is the one that helped you find the solution.